# Sketch: How to get a feathered mask?

Tags: mask, sketch-app, blur

[image: Just like the heading says]
How can I make the edge of a mask blurred/feathered like this example in Sketch?

Comment: I don't think the question marked as duplicate is a good target - consider instead: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/84350/how-do-i-feather-a-mask-in-sketch/119104#119104, which now documents achieving this exact effect.

Answer (score 0):

Make a selection then choose Select>Modify>Feather... Choose how many pixels to feather then create your mask from the feathered selection.

Comment: Oh sorry.. I just noticed this was sketch, not photoshop.. sorry, its late.